# Refreshing DropdownList data, after a new item has been selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist, one is State and one is City.  When a State is selected, the City dropdownlist becomes populated.  At that point you can select a city, however if you select a city and go back and select a different state, the city dropdownlist is populated by the cities for both states.  How do I get it clear the cities for the first state?

Here is the code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear()
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("@State", DbType.String, ddlState.SelectedValue))
        ddlCity.DataBind()
        'SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear()
        'Dim State As String = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCity.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Dim City As String = ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Public Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         
   SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear()         
   SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("@State", DbType.String, ddlState.SelectedValue))  
   ddlCity.Items.Clear();
   ddlCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELECT ONE", ""))  ' If you want it '       
   ddlCity.DataBind()
End Sub
```

You could also set `AppendDataboundItems = 'false'` in the control.

Comment: The code you placed, didn't seem to solve the problem.  But when I put the AppendDataboundItems ='false' it worked halfway.  But now nothing populates the city ddl... Any thoughts on how to fix this.  I do appreciate the response it is pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Post your Markup for the ddl.  If you include the Datasource control and state ddl will probably give best picture.  If you are in an update panel that too.